# Injecting lodash in Karma

Tags: karma-jasmine, lodash

I have injected lodash in ionic angular app. i have created a factory to register it as '_' and it's working fine while i run the app.

While i am writing unit test for that using Karma + jasmine and one of the service dependency injects '_' in it. It gives **Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: _Provider <- _ <- Dispatcher <- UserService.** As i dig more into it, i found provider as a string has been appended to '_' when it tries to inject the dependency.

Changed the order of loading lodash factory dependency in karma.conf but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the reference to Lodash in your `node_modules` directory is in the `files[]` property of your `karma.conf.js` file:

```
...
files: [
  'node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js',
  // Other files listed here...
],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it as `import * as _ from 'lodash'` instead of `import _ from 'lodash'` in the file that is being tested. No changes elsewhere. I think that Karma is not happy with the default exports.

That worked for me.